deploy to elastic beastalk error: Unable to download from S3 location. Reason: Bad Request
i'rying to create a pipeline in gitlab to deploy my app to elastic beanstalk but got An error occurred (InvalidParameterCombination) when calling the CreateApplicationVersion operation: Unable to download from S3 location. Reason: Bad Request. anyone know how to fix this?

gitlab.ci.yml
stages:
  - build
  - package
  - test
  - deploy

variables:
  APP_VERSION: $CI_PIPELINE_IID

build website:
  stage: build
  image: node:20-alpine
  script:
    - yarn install
    - yarn build
    - echo $APP_VERSION > dist/version.html
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - dist

build docker image:
  stage: package
  image: docker:26.1.2
  services:
    - docker:26.1.2-dind
  script:
    - echo $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD | docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER $CI_REGISTRY --password-stdin
    - docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE -t $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$APP_VERSION .
    - docker image ls
    - docker push --all-tags $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE

test docker image:
  stage: test
  image: curlimages/curl
  services:
    - name: $CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$APP_VERSION
      alias: website
  script:
    - curl http://website/version.html | grep $APP_VERSION

deploy production:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    APP_NAME: clean-city-dashboard
    APP_ENV_NAME: clean-city-dashboard-env
  environment: production
  image:
    name: amazon/aws-cli:2.15.38
    entrypoint: [""]
  script:
    - aws --version
    - yum install -y gettext
    - export DEPLOY_TOKEN=$(echo $GITLAB_DEPLOY_TOKEN | tr -d "\n" | base64)
    - envsubst < config/Dockerrun.aws.json > Dockerrun.aws.json
    - envsubst < config/auth.json > auth.json
    - cat Dockerrun.aws.json
    - cat auth.json
    - aws s3 cp Dockerrun.aws.json s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/Dockerrun.aws.json
    - aws s3 cp auth.json s3://$AWS_S3_BUCKET/auth.json
    - aws elasticbeanstalk create-application-version --application-name "$APP_NAME" --version-label $APP_VERSION --source-bundle S3Bucket=$AWS_S3_BUCKET,S3Key=Dockerrun.aws.json
    - aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --application-name "$APP_NAME" --version-label $APP_VERSION --environment-name $APP_ENV_NAME

Dockerrun.aws.json
{
    "AWSEBDockerrunVersion": "1",
    "Image": {
      "Name": "$CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE:$APP_VERSION"
    },
    "Authentication": {
      "Bucket": "$AWS_S3_BUCKET",
      "Key": "auth.json"
    },
    "Ports": [
      {
        "ContainerPort": 80
      }
    ]
  }

auth.json
{
    "auths": {
        "$CI_REGISTRY": {
            "auth": "$DEPLOY_TOKEN"
        }
    }
}


Maybe surround S3Bucket and S3Key values inside double quotes ""?

@ArpitJain tried that, still got the same error
